# Passing parameter ID in URL from GridBoundColumn (GridView) with JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, parameter-passing

I am using ASP.NET with C#
With the code above with JS i open new window info.aspx . I am trying to pass a parameter in the URL of info.aspx to know the id (RouteNo) of witch item was pressed to show the info of this item.
the lines that are comments is the way that I have try to take the Id of the RouteNo.

What I am doing wrong and how I can do it? Is there a way?

routedoc.aspx

```
<script>

        var popUpObj;
      //  var par = dataItem["RouteNo"];
         function RowClick(sender, eventArgs) {
             // popUpObj = window.open("Info.aspx?" + para + "",
             popUpObj = window.open("Info.aspx?",
             "ModalPopUp",
             "toolbar=no," +
             "scrollbars=no," +
             "location=no," +
             "statusbar=no," +
             "menubar=no," +
             "resizable=0," +
             "width=500," +
             "height=500," +
             "left = 300," +
             "top=150"
             );
             popUpObj.focus();
             LoadModalDiv();
         }


     function LoadModalDiv()
     {
         var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
         bcgDiv.style.display="block";
     }

     function HideModalDiv() {
         var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
         bcgDiv.style.display = "none";
     }
</script>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" GroupPanelPosition="Top" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" Skin="Glow" AllowPaging="True"  >
        <ExportSettings>
            <Pdf PageWidth="">
            </Pdf>
        </ExportSettings>
        <ClientSettings>
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"  />
            <ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClick" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientDataKeyNames="RouteNo" PageSize="20"  >
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn  DataField="RouteNo" HeaderText="RouteNo"  SortExpression="RouteNo"/>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Recipient"  HeaderText="Recipient" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Recipient"/>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DocHandle" HeaderText="DocHandle" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DocHandle" />
               <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Sender" HeaderText="Sender" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sender" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TermNo" HeaderText="TermNo" SortExpression="TermNo" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SentDate" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" HeaderText="SentDate" SortExpression="SentDate" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DueDate" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" HeaderText="DueDate" SortExpression="DueDate" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SentTime" HeaderText="SentTime" SortExpression="SentTime" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DueTime" HeaderText="DueTime" SortExpression="DueTime" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="Action" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" SortExpression="Notes" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BUDate" HeaderText="BUDate" SortExpression="BUDate" />
           <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Select"  UniqueName="AssetId" >
                <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
               </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
    <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server"  Text="Delete" OnClick="RadButton1_Click" Skin="Office2010Black" style="position: relative;">
    </telerik:RadButton>
```

Comment: You must be getting something in function when you click on row.

Comment: i have try to get it with var par = dataItem["RouteNo"];

Comment: Yes i know but i mean when you click on row noting is passed to function by default ?

Comment: Try this <ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClick(this)" /> and check if you get something in function and pass and argument to function like this function RowClick(row) {}.

Comment: I have try it and is not working

Comment: did you get row in function alert row and check what it gives  you ?

Comment: I have put your like this:  function RowClick(row) { popUpObj = window.open("Info.aspx?"+ row +"" , ........ And replaced RowClick with RowClick(row) correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75374/discussion-between-marios-and-mairaj-ahmad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your javascript function

```
var routeId = eventArgs.getDataKeyValue('RouteNo');
```

You will get routeid and you can pass it.